# Sharepoint: Is there some OOB way to delete provision files?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm using OOB functionality to upload files to sharepoint. I'm using `<module`> tags and feature which wraps all data. (it is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441170.aspx))

Here is example of module in my elements.xml file:

```
<Module Name="SampleImages" Url="Style Library/Images/SampleImages" Path="Images" RootWebOnly="TRUE">
    <File IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" Name="example.jpg" Url ="example.jpg" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
</Module>
```

The only problem is that when I deactivate feature uploaded files are not removed. Currently I use feature receiver which removes theese files, since I wasn't able to find any other solution.

So do I miss something or this is the only way how I can get rid of files uploaded in this manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the way you are doing it is the only way.

Answer (score 2):

By default SharePoint doesn't remove any of the provisioned files. If you want to clean things up on deactivation you have to do it manually using a FeatureReceiver.